# Java jersey monitoring statistics

Tags: java, jersey-2.0

I am trying to activate the monitoring  statistics for a web service. But i get null pointer exception. How is it activated properly? I do not understand the documentation from jersey. Here is my code:

```
package com.app.rest;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Provider;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerProperties;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.monitoring.MonitoringStatistics;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.monitoring.TimeWindowStatistics;
@Path("/")
public class TestingEvents extends ResourceConfig {
public TestingEvents()
{
    ResourceConfig cnf =   new ResourceConfig(TestingEvents.class);
     cnf.property(ServerProperties.MONITORING_ENABLED, true);
}



@Inject
 Provider<MonitoringStatistics> monitoringStatisticsProvider;

@Path("/test")
@GET
public void test()
{
    System.out.println("Invoked.........");
    final MonitoringStatistics snapshot = monitoringStatisticsProvider.get();

    System.out.println(snapshot.getRequestStatistics().toString());
 //  final TimeWindowStatistics timeWindowStatistics = snapshot.getRequestStatistics().getTimeWindowStatistics().get(0);
    //System.out.println("request count: " + timeWindowStatistics.getRequestCount()+", average request processing [ms]: " + timeWindowStatistics.getAverageDuration());
}}
```

and my web xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee       http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
<display-name>RestCounter</display-name>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>MyApplication</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.app.rest</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyApplication</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/myApp/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And the exception:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [MyApplication] in context with path     [/RestCounter] threw exception [java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.app.rest.TestingEvents.test(TestingEvents.java:34)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:143)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:160)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.VoidVoidDispatcherProvider$VoidToVoidDispatcher.doDispatch(VoidVoidDispatcherProvider.java:78)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:97)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:303)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:286)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1072)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:399)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:381)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:344)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:221)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1086)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:659)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1558)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1515)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Invoked is shown at the console but then the program crushes. help please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First get some configuration aspects out the way...

`ResourceConfig` is kind of a replacement for a web.xml. They *can* be used together, as you can configure the web.xml to use your `ResourceConfig` subclass, but I rarely see the need to. If you want to go with no web.xml, you could do something like

```
@ApplicationPath("/myApp")
public class AppConfig extends ResourceConfig {
    public AppConfig() {
        packages("com.app.rest");
    }
}
```

This is the equivalent to you declaring the `ServletContainer`, setting the package(s) to scan, and setting the url-mapping to `/myApp/*`. With the above configuration, you can completely get rid of the web.xml (assuming you have the `jersey-container-servlet` dependency, and you are in a Servlet 3.x environment; in a Servlet 2.x environment, you need to use the web.xml).

One thing you *do not* do, is have your resource classes extending `ResourceConfig`. So get rid of the sub-classing (in your `TestingEvents` class), and *definitely* get rid of what you have in the constructor.

#### As far as setting the monitoring property...

**If you decide to go with the `ResourceConfig` subclass...**

you can simple do

```
@ApplicationPath("/myApp")
public class AppConfig extends ResourceConfig {
    public AppConfig() {
        packages("com.app.rest");
        property(ServerProperties.MONITORING_STATISTICS_ENABLED, true);
    }
}
```

**If you decide to go with the `web.xml`...**

You should keep the [javadoc of the `ServerProperties`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.17/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ServerProperties.html#MONITORING_STATISTICS_ENABLED) handy. Each of the static fields, have String values, which for the most part can be configured in the web.xml as an `<init-param>` of the Jersey Servlet.  If you look at the [`ServerProperties.MONITORING_STATISTICS_ENABLED`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.17/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ServerProperties.html#MONITORING_STATISTICS_ENABLED), you will see that String value is

```
jersey.config.server.monitoring.statistics.enabled
```

So to set it as an init-param, do this

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>MyApplication</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.app.rest</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.monitoring.statistics.enabled</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer peeskillet!!! I have just figured out the web.xml part and the init-param. Thank you again! Problem solved!